# I am trying to display my scraped data onto my Django home template. I have filled in my views having problems with my html template

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping, django-views, django-templates

I created a python **scraper** that I need it to display as my Django home.html template. The code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


top_stories = []


def get_stories():
    """ user agent to facilitates end-user interaction with web content"""

    headers = {
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36'
    }

    base_url = 'https://www.jse.co.za/'

    source = requests.get(base_url).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

    articles = soup.find_all("article", class_="card")

   

    for article in articles:
        try:
            headline = article.h3.text.strip()
            link = base_url + article.a['href']
            text = article.find(
                "div", class_="field--type-text-with-summary").text.strip()
            img_url = base_url + article.picture.img['data-src']

            # print(headline, link, text, img_url)

            stories_dict = {}
            stories_dict['Headline'] = headline
            stories_dict['Link'] = link
            stories_dict['Text'] = text
            stories_dict['Image'] = img_url

            top_stories.append(stories_dict)

        except AttributeError as ex:
            print('Error:', ex)
    return top_stories
```

My views I  a created a function to display the list dictionary of the **scraped** data. I Import get_stories() from scrap_JSE.py in web_scraping app, defined home_page_view as a function based view. Set the variable jse_articles to the output of the function get_stories()

```
""" Import get_stories() from scrap_JSE.py in web_scraping app"""
from web_scraping.scrap_JSE import get_stories

""" Define home_page_view as a function based view. """
def home_page_view(request):

    """ Set the variable jse_articles to the output of the function get_stories(). """
    jse_articles = get_stories()

    """ Add the jse_articles variable to the views context dictionary for use in the template. """
    context = {
        'jse_articles' : jse_articles,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

I now need help to display iterate through my list dictionary my home page so far this is my code on my template. I would like to display my dictionary which has Headlines, Link, Text and URL image

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Home
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<h1> homepage </h1>



<p>Display News</p>



<ul>

{% for key,value in jse_articles. Items %}
    <li><a href="{{key}}">{{value}}</a></li>




    

{% endfor %}
</ul>

 

    
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
    
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: FYI it’s __scraped__ and __scraper__ not scrapped or scrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved it my html page now displaying. I need help with my link tag

```
{% for item in jse_articles %}
    <h3>{{ item.Headline }}</h3>
    <br>{{ item.Link}}<br> 
    {{item.Text}}
    <img src ="{{item.Image}}">
```